# Snap.svg: How to use Set.bind(...)?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I can't figure out how to use the Set.bind(...) feature for Snap.svg.

Below is an example with three(3) elements in a set: 2 circles and an ellipse.
I'd like to access and change some attr's in the various elements, using bind.

A few examples of bind would be appreciated.

(Actually, at this moment, I can't see any advantage in using the Set object, rather than an array. Are there any features of the Set that can't be handled just as well with an array?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svgDiscovery.com/_SNP/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg id=mySVG width=400 height=200></svg>
<script>
    var SNPsvg = Snap("#mySVG");
    var circle1 = SNPsvg.circle(150,100,50).attr({fill: 'red' });
    var circle2 = SNPsvg.circle(250,100,50).attr({fill: 'blue' });
    var ellipse = SNPsvg.ellipse(200,100,50,20).attr({fill: 'green' });

    var mySet= Snap.set(circle1,circle2,ellipse)

   setTimeout(function()
   {
         //mySet.bind(...)

    },1000)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to use a set, is that you can act on every element with a single command. For example...

```
mySet.animate({ transform: 's2' },1000)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzug0sbp/2/)

Which will then act on every single element with that animation.

Why would you use Set.bind ? I must admit, I've never used it, nor seen the purpose yet, but I assume there is one :).

So to the actual question, how is it used. I guess you do..

```
mySet.bind('x', circle1, 'cx' )
mySet.attr({ 'x': '200' })
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzug0sbp/4/)

If you set attribute x, it will set attribute cx on circle1 in this case.

Or

```
mySet.bind('x', function( val ) { console.log( val, ' is passed' )} )
mySet.attr({ 'x': '200' })
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzug0sbp/7/)

As to why though, I'm not sure :), I can see the advantage of using a set object, but not particularly with set.bind(), especially as it doesn't seem to pass 'this' to the function. I was wondering if it was something like if you set x on a set of circles and rects, you could adjust cx OR x somehow, but I don't see how that is done in any simple way, if the object that's being acted on isn't passed somehow.

I'd normally be more inclined to do something like...

```
mySet.forEach( function( el ) { el.attr({ fill: 'blue' }) } );
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ian. I agree that the Set's single command and the forEach are its most useful features.